# What are transforming approaches that collect array items from a nested data-structure into a single flat array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, data-structures, flatten

Given is a nested data-structure which I want to get transformed into a single flat array of non nested array-items.

The data and the code I came up with so far are as follows ...

```js
const data = [{
  heading: [{
    name: "Heading 01",
    Items: [{
      name: "Item 01",
      layers: [{
        name: "layer01",
        id: 4,
        parent: 3,
        droppable: false,
      }, {
        name: "layer02",
        id: 5,
        parent: 3,
        droppable: false,
      }],
      id: 3,
      parent: 2,
      droppable: true,
    }],
    id: 2,
    parent: 1,
    droppable: true,
  }],
  id: 1,
  parent: 0,
  droppable: true,
}];

const flatArray = [];
const flatObject = {};
  
for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
  for (const prop in data[index]) {

    const value = data[index][prop];

    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        for (const inProp in value[i]) {
          flatObject[inProp] = value[i][inProp];
        }
      }
    } else {
      flatObject[prop] = value;
    }
  }
  flatArray.push(flatObject);
}

console.log(flatArray)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... and the result is expected to be equal to the next provided data structure ...

```
[{
  id: 1,
  parent: 0,
  droppable: true,
}, {
  name: "Heading 01",
  id: 2,
  parent: 1,
  droppable: true,
}, {
  name: "Item 01",
  id: 3,
  parent: 2,
  droppable: true,
}, {
  name: "layer01",
  id: 4,
  parent: 3,
  droppable: false,
}, {
  name: "layer02",
  id: 5,
  parent: 3,
  droppable: false,
}]
```

Comment: Can you describe 'flatJSON' this is not some kind of standard as far as I know. Perhaps show the intended output?

Comment: @Evert
Json : 

`const obj = { "two": {  "three": 3 },"four": { "five": 5,"six": { "seven": 7 },"eight": 8},"nine": 9};`

Flat JSON
`const output = {
   'one': 1,
   'two.three': 3,
   'four.five': 5,
   'four.six.seven': 7,
   'four.eight': 8,
   'nine': 9
};`

Comment: @AdityaAdhikari that makes no sense in the context of the original question.

Comment: @Evert Not able to edit it in proper format but you can have idea from above comment :D

Comment: May this link can help you :
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flattening-a-json-object-in-javascript

Comment: @Evert I have added output as well, Thanks

Comment: @AdityaAdhikari I have added output as well, Thanks

Comment: Please remove references to JSON! You have a JavaScript Array and at no point are you doing any (de)serialization.

Comment: Voted to reopen as this does not seem to lack focus or clarity.  It shows the input format, the requested output format, and demonstrates a reasonable attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could come up with a recursive approach which targets specific array items by any wanted array's key/identifier which are all going to be used by a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) with [default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_value) and [rest property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property).

The advantage of the destructuring is the separation and the direct access of all relevant data, the possible to be targeted array(s) and the rest of the currently processed data item.

```js
function collectSpecificArrayItemsRecursively(data) {
  const result = [];

  if (Array.isArray(data)) {

    result
      .push(
        ...data
          .flatMap(collectSpecificArrayItemsRecursively)
      );
  } else {

    const {
      // destructuring into specific
      // arrays and the data's rest.
      heading = [], Items = [], layers = [], ...rest
    } = data;

    result
      .push(
        rest,
        ...heading
          .concat(Items)
          .concat(layers)
          .flatMap(collectSpecificArrayItemsRecursively),
      );    
  }
  return result;
}
const data = [{
  heading: [{
    name: "Heading 01",
    Items: [{
      name: "Item 01",
      layers: [{
        name: "layer01",
        id: 4,
        parent: 3,
        droppable: false,
      }, {
        name: "layer02",
        id: 5,
        parent: 3,
        droppable: false,
      }],
      id: 3,
      parent: 2,
      droppable: true,
    }],
    id: 2,
    parent: 1,
    droppable: true,
  }],
  id: 1,
  parent: 0,
  droppable: true,
}];

console.log(
  collectSpecificArrayItemsRecursively(data)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not really in a recursive structure.  So, while we can write a function that will do the transform, it's more complex and more fragile than one would hope.

Here is one possibility:

```js
const flatten = (data) =>
  data .flatMap (({heading = [], Items = [], layers = [], ...rest}) => [
    rest, 
    ...flatten (heading), 
    ...flatten (Items), 
    ...flatten (layers)
  ])

const data = [{heading: [{name: "Heading 01", Items: [{name: "Item 01", layers: [{name: "layer01", id: 4, parent: 3, droppable: !1}, {name: "layer02", id: 5, parent: 3, droppable: !1}], id: 3, parent: 2, droppable: !0}], id: 2, parent: 1, droppable: !0}], id: 1, parent: 0, droppable: !0}]

console .log (flatten (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The fragility I mention has to do with the fact that we specifically have to hard-code the levels here, `heading`, `Items`, `layers`.  That they are indiscriminately capitalized and pluralized is a minor problem.  The major problem is that they are all *different*.  We are searching every level for each possible name for its children.  And if we reused a name for a different purpose at one level (say the top level also had `layers: 7`, this would fall apart.

However, if you're in charge of that format, you can simplify it by combining these under the name, `children`.  That will lead to simpler, more robust code, and more consistent data structures.

It would mean making your input look like this:

```js
const data = [{
  children: [{          // the node formerly known as `heading`
    name: "Heading 01",
    children: [{        // the node formerly known as `Items`
      name: "Item 01",
      children: [{      // the node formerly known as `layers`
        name: "layer01",
        id: 4,
        parent: 3,
        droppable: false,
      }, {
        name: "layer02",
        id: 5,
        parent: 3,
        droppable: false,
      }],
      id: 3,
      parent: 2,
      droppable: true,
    }],
    id: 2,
    parent: 1,
    droppable: true,
  }],
  id: 1,
  parent: 0,
  droppable: true,
}]
```

The name `children` could be replaced with anything you like, as long as it's consistent.

With that, we could simply do this:

```js
const flatten = (data) =>
  data .flatMap (({children = [], ...rest}) => [rest, ...flatten (children)])

const data = [{children: [{name: "Heading 01", children: [{name: "Item 01", children: [{name: "layer01", id: 4, parent: 3, droppable: !1}, {name: "layer02", id: 5, parent: 3, droppable: !1}], id: 3, parent: 2, droppable: !0}], id: 2, parent: 1, droppable: !0}], id: 1, parent: 0, droppable: !0}]

console .log (flatten (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here we simply separate out `children` from the rest of the node, return the rest as a new object followed by the result of recurring on `children`.  This is an elegant little function, easy to write and easy to understand.  But it requires a consistent data format to get it to work.

Comment: @Sacrlett_jose ... This is the perfect answer to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```js
const c = (item: any) => "name" in item ? [{
  name: item.name,
  id: item.id,
  parent: item.parent,
  droppable: item.droppable
}] : []

function flat(item: any) {
  // "heading" is array of items
  // heading.map(function) will map over every heading and applies `function` to item
  if ("heading" in item) {
    // flatMap is .map(function).flat()
    return c(item).concat(item.heading.flatMap(flat))
  }

  // checking all cases where recursion goes deeper
  if ("Items" in item) {
    return c(item).concat(item.Items.flatMap(flat))
  }

  if ("layers" in item) {
    return c(item).concat(item.layers.flatMap(flat))
  }

  return c(item) // edge case, when there is no children items
}

console.log(data.flatMap(flat))
```

Explanation: I saw what you have recursive structure in your `data` variable. I started from creating a function `flat`, that will traverse all paths, and printing out the smallest piece, called `leaves`. Then I saw, that you need to have `name, id, parent, droppable` properties and creating helper function, that extracts all of these if any presents `"name" in item` is enough for that. Then just call helper on every step and concat with `item`.

Comment: Code-only answers are not nearly as helpful as those with explanatory text.  Could you [edit] to explain how this works?

Comment: @ScottSauyet, sorry, If you can edit my English, I will be very grateful

Comment: Your English here, while not entirely how a native speaker would write, is perfectly understandable.  There is no reason I see to edit it.  Nice job!  But you might want to read [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992).

Answer (score 0):

Recursive approach:

```js
const data = [{"id": 1,"parent": 0,"droppable": true,"heading": [{"name": "Heading 01","Items": [{"name": "Item 01","layers": [{"name": "layer01","id": 4,"parent": 3,"droppable": false},{"name": "layer02","id": 5,"parent": 3,"droppable": false}],"id": 3,"parent": 2,"droppable": true}],"id": 2,"parent": 1,"droppable": true}]}];
  
const iter = (data) => data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const entries = Object.entries(obj);
    const arrays = entries.filter(([, value]) => Array.isArray(value)); 
    const objWithoutArrays = entries
      .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => Array.isArray(value) 
        ? acc 
        : { ...acc, [key]: value }
      , {});
      
    acc.push(objWithoutArrays);
    acc.push(...arrays.flatMap(([, value]) => iter(value)));
    
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(iter(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```